# Angular execute XHR request without triggering a digest

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a scenario where I want to issue an XHR post to the server. I do not want to trigger a $rootScope.$digest() by doing so. I know I can manually create my own XMLHttpRequest to do this same thing, but I feel there should be a way to do this inside angularjs by default.

Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: doesn't using `$.ajax` outside of `$http` work just fine?

Comment: That requires you to have a dependency on jquery I believe.

Comment: Check out [$http:991](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L991), the only way to get around it is turning on `$rootScope.$$phase` _(a extremely fugly hack)_, using an external library to accomplish it, or simply not caring about whether a request triggers a `$digest` cycle. The last one is what you should be gunning for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [$http:991](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L991), the only way to get around it is turning on `$rootScope.$$phase` *(a extremely fugly hack)*, using an external library to accomplish it, or simply not caring about whether a request triggers a `$digest` cycle. The last one is what you should be gunning for.

Either *use a external library*, or get downright **nasty**.

```
$rootScope.$$phase = true;
$http.get('/foo').success(function () {
  $rootScope.$$phase = false;
});
```

Obviously **not reccomended** as lots of unexpected stuff might happen, so. Yeah, external library.

What you should really be doing is *not considering* getting around the whole point of Angular.js

Comment: I agree with the idea of not trying to get around angular. I should be able to adopt our approach to working with $http. Just figured there would be a way do to it. Fire a request that has no other effect. Fire and forget. Seems like there would be a way to do this that isn't too intrusive.